# Is it possible to distribute ajax responses to multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to get jQuery ajax responses in to multiple DIVs?

I would like to distribute the responses in different DIVs.

html

```
<div id="postrequest1"></div>
<div id="postrequest2"></div>
```

jQ

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#loaddata").click(function(){
        $.post("php/test2.php",
            { name:$("#txtinput").val(), 
            location:$("#txtlocation").val() },
            function(response) {
                $("#postrequest").html(response);
            });
    });
});
```

ph:

```
$post_name=$_POST["name"];
$post_location=$_POST["location"]; 

if( $post_name && $post_location){
    echo "Name: ". $post_name; // this should be displayed in postrequest1
    echo "Location: " .$post_location; // this should be displayed in postrequest2
}
```

Comment: You can put response in any number of div you want. What's the problem ?

Comment: I think the issue is splitting the php output into two pieces.

Comment: @joeshmo: thanks. yes, that was the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you change your php script to output JSON you can parse it in javascript and put it in the right places.

Try this in the php script:

```
$post_name=$_POST["name"];
$post_location=$_POST["location"]; 

if( $post_name && $post_location){
   $data = array();
   $data['name'] = $post_name;
   $data['location'] = $post_location;
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

It will output something like:

```
{'name': 'Fergoso', 'location': 'North Pole'}
```

Then in your javascript, you need to parse the response, then you can use it as an object in javascript:

```
function(response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    $("#postrequest1").html(data.name);
    $("#postrequest2").html(data.location);
});
```